# Bold text in li

Tags: html, css

I have the next element:

```
<li>
    "abcd"
    <div>something here</div>
    <div>and here</div>
</li>
```

without wrapping the text: `abcd` in span, there is an option to bold it with css?

I just want to bold this text, not the text of `something here` or `and here`.

```
font-weight:bold;
```

any help appreciated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try this

```
li{
    font-weight:bold;
}
li > div{
    font-weight:normal;
}
```

[Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hd6GA/)

If there is a possiblity of having different tags inside the `li` apart from `div` then you can use this selector as well

```
li > * {
    font-weight:normal;
}
```

[Js Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/hd6GA/4/)

Answer (score 4):

You can not target text nodes with CSS so you'll either have to wrap it in an element or do as Sachin says.